# How to Modify Choices of ModelMultipleChoiceField

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Let's say I have some contrived models:

```
class Author(Model):
   name = CharField()

class Book(Model):
   title = CharField()
   author = ForeignKey(Author)
```

And let's say I want to use a ModelForm for Book:

```
   class BookForm(ModelForm):
      class Meta:
         model = Book
```

Simple so far.  But let's also say that I have a ton of Authors in my database, and I don't want to have such a long multiple choice field.  So, I'd like is to restrict the queryset on the BookForm's ModelMultipleChoiceField author field.  Let's also say that the queryset I want can't be chosen until `__init__`, because it relies on an argument to be passed.

This seems like it might do the trick:

```
class BookForm(ModelForm):
   class Meta:
      model = Book

   def __init__(self, letter):
      # returns the queryset based on the letter
      choices = getChoices(letter)
      self.author.queryset = choices
```

Of course, if that just worked I wouldn't be here.  That gets me an AttributeError.  'BookForm' object has no attribute 'author'.  So, I also tried something like this, where I try to override the ModelForm's default field and then set it later:

```
class BookForm(ModelForm):
   author = ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Author.objects.all())

   class Meta:
      model = Book

   def __init__(self, letter):
      choices = getChoices(letter)
      self.author.queryset = choices
```

Which produces the same result.

Anyone know how this is intended to be done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Form objects don't have their fields as attributes, you need to look in the "fields" attribute, which is a dictionary:

```
self.fields['author'].queryset = choices
```

If you want to fully understand what's going on here, you might be interested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500650/django-model-question-newbie/501362#501362) - it's about Models, but Forms work similarly.

Comment: You answer is a bit misleading. The `queryset` attribute of the ModelMultipleChoiceField should be, as it states, a queryset. It will be used for validation. But `choices` refers to the field's widget and represents what would actually be rendered as select <option> tags.

Answer (score 10):

Although Carl is correct about the fields, you're also missing a super class call. This is how I do it:

```
class BookForm(ModelForm):
    author = ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Author.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Book

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        letter = kwargs.pop('letter')
        super(BookForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        choices = getChoices(letter)
        self.fields['author'].queryset = choices
```

Comment: Yeah, my real problem area has the super class call, but I skipped it for this example.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll leave this up for any one that wanders into this question for reference's sake, I guess.

Comment: Definitely.  It's important to see that the super().__init__() needs to happen before the access to fields.