# Newbie: In Django, how to I change the object display names?

Tags: django

Apologies for the simple question. I've tried searching the django docs for an answer, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

I have set up a couple classes, but in the admin area they are all coming up as 'classname object'. I tried using the code here:
[How do Django model fields work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500650/django-model-question-newbie)
.. but I got an enormous page of errors.

I have an abstract class of people, and then child classes of specialized people. I'm trying to get them to be listed as self.name but I can't for the life of me figure this out.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should implement a `__unicode__` method, like:

```
class Person(model.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s <%s>' % (self.name, self.email)
```

In that point if you try to `print` a Person object, it will use your `__unicode__` function.

Comment: Good answer, but please remember to recommend good practice: you should always return Unicode from the unicode method. Prefix the quotes with u.

Comment: so `return u.'%s' % (self.name)` ?

Comment: Yeah Daniel, good point. It will be `return u'%s <%s>' % (self.name, self.email)`