# Whats the difference between models and models.Model in django?(and similarly for forms and forms.Form )

Tags: django, oop, django-models

I know that "models" is a module of package django.db, But why we inherit like `class Foo(models.Model):` while the all required fields like CharField, IntegerField, etc. are part of models, what does the subclass Model do here exactly?

I am new to OOP and Django so any resources and answers are heavily appreciated and welcomed.

Comment: Well, the best resource is often the source code itself: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py. The base Model class and ir's metaclass actually automate a LOT of things, sparing you the need to write the same boilerplate code over and over again ;-)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers if I am not wrong, a metaclass is a class that defines how a class behaves, so class Model and its metaclass ModelBase does "some work" that converts models fields into database columns? but I am unclear regarding what "some work" in this context. It would be great if you can summarize with an example. Thanks for replying to this thread.

Comment: Python classes are objects, so they are instance of a class - that's what we call the metaclass. Custom metaclasses are typically used to hook into the class creation process. There's no shortage of literature on the topic (starting with official Python doc) so you should find better examples than what I could come with. Regarding Django's models, the Model's metaclass is in the file I linked to in my previous comment, it's named ModelBase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How do Django model fields work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500650/how-do-django-model-fields-work)
To use methods such as `save()`, `create()`, `delete()`, etc from Model class

Answer (score 1):

As you say, `models` is a package, that is, a set of classes / methods. For convenience, `models` and `forms` are imported only once and the classes they contain are used. Example: `models.CharField`, otherwise you would have to import the classes one by one (unnecessarily).
`Model` is a class to create entities in your database.

Comment: thanks for looking at this thread, I understand that models and its classes(fields) work as some sort of boilerplate code but I am not able to understand the functionality of Model subclass(especially while inheriting models.Model )